# Download image using service

Tags: android

i am new to android. i need to download one image and show that image in activity. i tried more i cant get the output.
anyone can help me?

```
public class Home_Appliances extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = Home_Appliances.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://quickiz.com/abdullah/json/pickspage?commonId=125";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

private TextView textView;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String string = bundle.getString(DownloadService.FILEPATH);
            int resultCode = bundle.getInt(DownloadService.RESULT);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(Home_Appliances.this,
                        "Download complete. Download URI: " + string,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textView.setText("Download done");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Home_Appliances.this, "Download failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textView.setText("Download failed");
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__appliances);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    /*adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, cityList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    JSONArray jsonarr = null;
                    try {
                        jsonarr = response.getJSONArray("productDetails");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {


                        JSONObject obj = null;
                        try {
                            obj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                            City city = new City();
                            city.setTitle(obj.getString("productName"));
                            city.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("Image"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            cityList.add(city);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadService.NOTIFICATION));
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

public void onClick(View view) {



    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
    // add infos for the service which file to download and where to store
    intent.putExtra(DownloadService.FILENAME, "MyImages");
    intent.putExtra(DownloadService.URL,cityList.get(0).getThumbnailUrl());
    startService(intent);
    textView.setText("Service started");
    System.out.println("-----URL image---------"+cityList.get(0).getThumbnailUrl());
}
}
```

this is my service class

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
public static final String URL = "urlpath";
public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
public static final String RESULT = "result";
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.vogella.android.service.receiver";

public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}

// will be called asynchronously by Android
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
    System.out.println("urlpath=================================>"+urlPath);
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
    File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            fileName);
    if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
        System.out.println("am in download if class=============================>");
    }

    InputStream stream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

       URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
        int next = -1;
        while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(next);
        }
        // successfully finished
        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
}

private void publishResults(String outputPath, int result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, outputPath);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Image view to hold the image, then use Picasso to download and insert the image in the imageview. Look up Square up Picasso library.

In your Gradle add the line:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Then in your activity: `Picasso.with(context).load("YourURL").into(imageView);`

imageView is your imageview you want it to be displayed in.

Comment: can u tell me how to use picasso here